# InlineKeyboard - проблема поля URL

Tags: telegram-bot

Посылается запрос по типу
*[https://api.tlgr.org/botТОКЕНБОТА/sendMessage?chat_id=598706644&text=ТЕСТ&parse_mode=HTML&reply_markup={](https://api.tlgr.org/bot%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%91%D0%9E%D0%A2%D0%90/sendMessage?chat_id=598706644&text=%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%A2&parse_mode=HTML&reply_markup=%7B)
"inline_keyboard" : [[{
"text" : "Открыть ссылку",
"url" : "https://linktoany.com/api?FirstPik=123&TwoPik=blaba"
}]]
}*
Выдается ошибка парсинга Json, а именно: *{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object"}*.
Но при этом если убрать из url амперсанд (&), то всё будет работать...
Возможно кто то знает как это решить?

Answer (score 0):

Решено. Вместо амперсанда ставлю \u0026. (\u0026)